# How to detect new servers starting/stopping in my network from my Java app

Tags: java

I have developed a load balancer in Java. It load balances incoming requests among a fix set of servers. But now these servers can startup/shutdown dynamically, and new servers can be added dynamically (what it means I don't have a fixed list of IP addresses).

I'd like to know what's the best way (from Java) to automatically discover new servers in the network (or detect that any server is shutting down and, therefore, stop sending requests to it).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a matter of concept. The best way to do this is to have a central manager where all the servers can register themselves and set their status if it changes. Your program could be that manager or, if you want to execute it anywhere, ask the manager for the registered servers. Of course you need at least one static machine for that and all your server programs have to be changed to perform the registration.

Otherwise your only choice is trying to connect to each server and assuming it is off if the connection fails. If you don't even know the IP you'd have to iterate over each possible IP which is a really bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java one possibility is to have a "register" server (good known, means fix IP or DNS entry) where new upcomming servers register that they are up and sending some heartbeat to signal they are alive.

The "register" server may have a REST interface to get system status easily for other interesting parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the port on which the server is listening like tomcat on 8080. Then periodically you can scan the port for all machines to check if the server is started on some machine.

You can scan each machine for that port by using java socket program or you can take help of UDP. But in either case you need to know socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

If your network supports multicast, then that's an option.  Tomcat actually uses multicast to do its service discovery for servlet clustering.

See [Tomcat's Clustering Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) for more details of how they do it, which might form a good starting point for you.